# Angular application render twice with ssr

Tags: angular, typescript, seo, server-side-rendering

I have  an Angular 12 application. I have recently enabled server-side rendering for GOOD SEO performance, but my application renders twice: once with static HTML, and once with the client side application. How can I overcome this?

Comment: You mean it renders again on the client? This is normal and can’t really be prevented.

Comment: Hi @MikeOne, but after server side rendered page renders again after a second white page and then client side startes rendering

Comment: Your production build will have aot enabled and your main bundle optimized, so you won't notice it at all. Just be sure to use route-level code-splitting (one module per page) and only import the dependency modules you **actually need**